# codemirror html mixed mode not being applied to JavaScript

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes

[image: codemirror issue]

```
$('.code').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
$code = $this.html();

$this.empty();

var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(this, {
    value: $code,
    mode: 'htmlmixed',
    lineNumbers: false,
    readOnly: true,
    lineWrapping: true
});
```

});

I'm using codemirror to create code snippets.  I'm having two issues.  The first is that javascript isn't being colored properly.  I've included all the dependencies (xml, css and js).  The second is that when I hover over the , scrolling causes the snippet to move slightly up or down.  It isn't quite scrolling, just wiggling.  See image for more details.

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The htmlmixed mode will only highlight JavaScript code in `<script>` tags, not magically recognize text in the document that happens to look like JavaScript

Comment: Thanks - I should have closed this as I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.code).each(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
     $code = $this.html(),
     $unescaped = $('<div/>').html($code).text();
     $this.empty();
     CodeMirror(this, {
      value: $unescaped,
      lineNumbers: true,
      theme: "neo",
      readOnly: "nocursor"
    });
   });
```

**This was working fine for me**